# bash: How to assign a directory name with spaces and single quotes to a variable

Tags: bash, variables, directory

Here is an example directory

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 vangryman 197121 0 Jul 29 13:27 "2022-07-29 13.26.09 Very Angryman's Personal Meeting Room"/
```

So i'm trying to get the directory name to later cd into it

```
$ cat get_zoom.sh

#!/bin/bash

dir=$(ls -tr ../../Downloads/Documents/Zoom/ | tail -1)

cd "\"\"$dir\"\""

pwd
```

But no joy with how i wrap quotes

```
$ sh -x get_zoom.sh

++ ls -tr ../../Downloads/Documents/Zoom/

++ tail -1

+ dir='2022-07-29 13.28.21 Very Angryman''\''s Personal Meeting Room'

+ cd '""2022-07-29 13.28.21 Very Angryman'\''s Personal Meeting Room""'

get_zoom.sh: line 3: cd: ""2022-07-29 13.28.21 Very Angryman's Personal Meeting Room"": No such file or directory
```

Comment: Why are you tagging this _bash_, when you run it as _sh_?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a problem with the assignment itself, unless you are using a very old version of the shell, in which case you sould have written

```
dir="$(.....)"
```

But your `cd` command is odd. It should be simple

```
cd "$dir"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking for the latest file, sort by reverse date, and pick the first item. Also, worth filter non-directories from being considered.

```
dir=$(ls -t ../../Downloads/Documents/Zoom/ | awk '/^d/ { print $1 ; exit }' )
cd "$dir"
```